find an ellipse equation satisfied

In the standard coordinate system of $E^2$, given the second-degree
curve S with the equation: $$5x^2+8xy+5y^2-18x-18y+9=0$$ a) Prove that
$(S)$ is an ellipse.
b) Write the equation of the ellipse with the
same axis of symmetry as $(S)$, but with semi-axes doubled compared to
the given ellipse.


PS: I already done part a). By finding eigenvalues of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 5& 4\\ 4& 5\end{bmatrix}$, I set $$\begin{cases} x=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x_1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y_1\\ y=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x_1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y_1\end{cases}.$$ Then $(S)$ becomes $$x_1^2+9(y_1-\sqrt{2})^2=9$$
Again, I set  $$\begin{cases}x_2=x_1\\ y_2=y_1-\sqrt{2}\end{cases}$$ Then (S) becomes $$\dfrac{x_2^2}{9}+y_2^2=1$$ which is an ellipse equation. I'm stuck at part b) though. I would be very appreciated if someone could help me wit part b). Thanks in advance!

$\frac {x_2^2}{3^2} + \frac {y_2^2}{1^2} = 1$
Double the axes would be
$\frac {x_2^2}{6^2} + \frac {y_2^2}{2^2} = 1$
And if you think it is necessary, reverse the substitutions.
$x_2^2 + 9y_2^2 = 36$
$x_1^2 + 9(y_1 - \sqrt 2)^2 = 36$
$y_1 = \frac {x+y}{\sqrt 2}\\
x_1 = \frac {x+y}{\sqrt 2}$
A more linear algebra way to do it would be.
$x^TAx + bx - 9 =0$
Diagonlize $A$
$x^TP^T\pmatrix {9&0\\0&1}Px + bx + 9 = 0$
Double the major axes
$x^TP^T\pmatrix {\frac {9}{4}&0\\0&\frac {1}{4}}Px + bx + 9 = 0$

@Harry Misread the question. Thought they wanted just the major axis doubled
